# Url Display on web and database

Tags: url, cakephp, url-rewriting, url-routing, cakephp-2.0

Everytime I want to change my url, I have to do at my database.

This is my code at index.ctp. I can't rename it at the web. I have to do at phpmyadmin.

```
<?php
  echo $this->Form->input('Company.forum_url',
      array('label'=>false , 'maxlength' => '10')
  );
?>
```

Someone please help me.

Comment: I'm not really following you. First of all, why would you have to keep changing your URL? Second of all, is that form code not working to save the value to the forum_url field of the companies table?

Comment: Please start learning how to ask proper questions: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: sorry for my inproper question. this is my first time. thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you need to know the address of your website you can find it in the $_SERVER super global:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

CakePHP is more than happy to run in any directory/url without you having name your links specifically.

The HTML helper has a handy link() method that takes care of that for you:

```
echo $this->Html->link('link label', '/foo/bar/1');
```

or

```
echo $this->Html->link('link label', array('controller'=>'foos', 'action'=>'bar', 1));
```

will create a link that works irrespective of the host name or the url the link is being displayed on.

You can get the path to your applications web root with (useful for passing into javascripts):

```
$root = Router::url('/');
```

Comment: thnks for the answer. just need to ask, what does action do??

Comment: action is the method in your controller you want to invoke.